# Batch Apex on LastLogin

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I'm trying to use batch apex on Lastlogindate. I have to capture the system generated lastlogindate into a custom field .Here is the code

```
global class CaptureLastLoginDate implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

//This is the query that is passed to the execute method.  .

String query = 'SELECT id, LastLoginDate FROM User WHERE Id=:UserInfo.getUserId()';

global database.queryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return database.getQueryLocator(query);

} 
//close start method
global void  execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<User> scope) {
User u = [SELECT id, LastLoginDate FROM User WHERE Id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];


   // Iterate through the whole query 
    for(User a : scope) {

            a.LastLoginDate__c = u.LastLoginDate;
        } //close if statement
     update LastLoginDate__c;
     }

    //close for-loop

 //close execute method

  global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {


  } //close finish method
} //close class
```

and the error i'm getting is**

:E**rror: Compile Error: Argument type of global method must also be global: LIST at line 12 column 15**

Thank you in advance

**

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of your question at http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Batch-apex/m-p/714191. Why are you asking the same in two different places at once?

Comment: @FrankZ: I don't see anything wrong with asking the same question in two places, not all users are active members of both sites.

Comment: @PepeFloyd it's the "at once" I was more concerned about. As long as Sindoora keeps all forums updated about discussions going on in the other places it's fine by me.

Comment: @Frankz Hi,Frankz  all the salesforce users are not activate members in stack. That's y i posted in two different place.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you get that error message. I can save the class using API v29 after making some other changes (more on that later). Which API version is this class using?

To save the class I had to change `update LastLoginDate__c;` to `update scope;`. Then the system complained about LastLoginDate__c not existing within User. Removing the __c caused the system to tell me that this field is not modifiable - and rightly so.

Maybe you should go back to the drawing board with your idea. Not sure what you try to achieve using this class.

Oh, and one more thing: I think `UserInfo.getUserId()` will return null in a Batch APEX context.

Comment: Thanks.Error has been resolved.The reson y i got error is:already there exists and apex class on user so that it fired error message.

Comment: @Frankz.In this code we are trying to capture system generated LastLoginDate into a custom Field(LastLogionDate__c) on user. Generally on User few field are not exposed like createdby,LastLogin,... to get those fields info we use UserInfo.getUserId()

Comment: Sindoora, it would be great if you would write up the answer, post it, and mark your question as answered for other people who might struggle with this problem. Much thanks!